# How to carry over or retain values from URL?

Tags: html, forms, url, get

So,  I have a site that allows user to search for properties listed

There's a search bar on homepage that allows them to search by keyword (e.g. city)

This leads to /search-results/?keyword="input"   (e.g. /search-results/?keyword="glasgow" )

I have added a sorting menu to the results page:

```
<form class="propertyhive-ordering" method="get">
    <select name="orderby" class="orderby">
        <option value="floor_area-desc">Sort by floor area: high to low</option>
        <option value="floor_area-asc">Sort by floor area: low to high</option>
        
    </select>
</form>
```

However, this completely replaces ?keyword="glasgow" this results in **all** properties being shown, rather than just matches
**
How do I keep the info from ?keyword= ?
**

i'm aware I need to add a hidden field, i.e.

```
<input type="hidden" name="keyword" value=".......
```

but stumped at what value needs to be

Comment: what programming language is your website coded in?

Comment: @CornelRaiu html :)

Comment: Aham. Can you show me how does your website handle sorting via HTML? Also, how does it search for stuff with HTML? 

I will just assume you have PHP on the server side. In that case, the value in your hidden input should look like `value="<?php echo $_GET['keyword'] ?>"`

Comment: @CornelRaiu  Thanks so much for your help. 
No idea how to answer being perfectly honest, but you can check out run of it here https://wordpress-249005-2966670.cloudwaysapps.com/home-2.

Its just a WP site with custom post types as "properties". The homepage search bar runs a keyword search (?keyword="..." in url)

Comment: It looks like you added the PHP code using the Beaver Builder HTML module.That will never execute correctly. Unfortunately, in this case, you'll need a WP developer to help. In order to do this you need to either create a custom BB module that allows you to insert that sort, or write a custom shortcode that will then allow you to add it in the BB HTML module

Comment: @CornelRaiu Thanks so much for your expert insight - got it sorted off the back of your advice with a shortcode!

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Inserted the below in a Universal snippet with [Woody Snippets](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/insert-php/) plugin

```
<form class="propertyhive-ordering" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="keyword" value= "<?php echo $_GET['keyword'] ?>">
    <select name="orderby" class="orderby">
        <option value="floor_area-desc">Sort by floor area: high to low</option>
        <option value="floor_area-asc">Sort by floor area: low to high</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Added shortcode to layout

(thanks again for the guidance Cornel Raiu!)